# Android : IntentService or Handler

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, intentservice

I'm meeting a problem to understand which is the best solution for what I want to do. (And I've problems to understand ATM how they work exactly)

Often I use Asynctask, but in this case I think it's not what I need.

In an activity (A) I want to start a task which sends datas to a WS and it can take 10-20 secondes to be done. I want to allow the user to do otherthing on the app during this time.

When this task is done, I want to call another activity, but if there are errors, I want to show them in a toast. I want too, to show a progressbar if the user is on this activity (A).

So I see that IntentService can help me, because it's not "linked" to an activity, it works in background etc... but it seems a little complicated to have a link with the UI Thread. (in my case, if there is a problem, I want to do something in my activity A).

The other part, the handler can be used, but if the activity is destroyed, the thread runs always, but how can I "restore" the link with the activity if the users come back on the activity (A) ? (with a static class to save it ?).

So if you have any links/advise/other to give me more explanation, I will appreciate it :) (I readed the Android's doc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, use an IntentService - they're designed for exactly this kind of thing. The second part of your question takes a little longer to answer, but bear with me ;-)

Essentially one of two things can happen whilst your IntentService is busy talking to the server: 1) the user navigates away from your, 2) the user stays in your app. You can account for this by doing the following:

1. Your IntentService should send an Ordered Broadcast when it has completed with the information on whether or not it was successful.
2. For the activities that you want to react to this broadcast, create a base implementation for them which registers a broadcast receiver in onResume() and gets rid of it in onPause(). These should cancel the broadcast if they react to it
3. Create a second (but stand-alone) broadcast receiver for your broadcast and register it in the manifest with a priority 0 so it will always be the last to know about your IntentService finishing. This receiver is responsible for creating a notification for the user to click, which will take them to the relevant place in your app.

Here's a barebones manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="bubblebearapps.co.uk.blah" >

<permission android:name="change_this_name"
    android:label="my_permission"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="change_this_name"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"

        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"
        android:permission="change_this_name">
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <action android:name="action_name_here"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Barebones activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String YOUR_ACTION = "this_action_matches_the_one_in_the_manifest";
public static final String YOUR_PERMISSION = "this_permission_matches_the_one_in_the_manifest";


private InterceptsReciever mReceiver;

private void doSomethingWithBroadcast(Intent intent) {
    // this method must return quickly! If you've got something long to do, do it on a background thread
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mReceiver = new InterceptsReciever(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public static class InterceptsReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private final MainActivity mainActivity;

    public InterceptsReciever(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(YOUR_ACTION);
        filter.setPriority(1); //anything above the manifest. You could have higher priorities for nested fragments or whatever if you like....

        mainActivity.registerReceiver(this,
                filter, 
                YOUR_PERMISSION,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (YOUR_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            mainActivity.doSomethingWithBroadcast(intent);
            abortBroadcast(); // this prevents other the manifest broadcast being called

        }

    }
}


/**
 * Example of how to send broadcasts
 * @param context
 */
public static void sendBroadcast(Context context){

    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTION);

    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(
            intent,
            YOUR_PERMISSION        // this protects your broadcast from being seen by just anyone
    );

}



}
```

Comment: Thx for your help :) First question, why IntentService is better than an Handler for this case ? Because it seems to be - maybe - easier to do something with an handler ?

Comment: IntentService has a little more boilerplate I'll admit, but it has its own lifecycle and context so is less bug-prone. 

Also the major benefit of an IntentSevice is that you can fire off as many as your heart desires, but it'll only run one at a time! This means you don't even have to worry about how many threads you have open etc

Comment: Ok I understand ! I'm going to try this, will see, I will back if I've a problem :D

Comment: Hey ! How can I do to check in my service if the app is in foreground ?

Comment: Step 2 in my answer should cover that, they'll intercept the broadcast your service will send

Comment: When the app is in background, the code :

            Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction(Receiver.ACTION_RESP);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

Doesn't work, the receiver isn't called :(

Comment: Have you declared a broadcast receiver that will listen for that action in your manifest?

Comment: Yes :/ And it seems it doesn't found it :/

Comment: Ok I found the problem, but I've another. I want to do some action if I'm on the same activity. So I used  :

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this) to register the action, and unregister in onPause method to delete it. But if I do unregister, the receiver declared in the manifest wasn't called. (and so, nothing happend when the app is in background.)

How can I do ? How can I check if I'm on the activity, or if the app is in background ?  (I see I can put a boolean in class parent, but I dont think it's the solution.)

Comment: Mhhh I read again your comment, and so I created two receivers. One for my activity (that I'm using with register, unregister) and the other in the manifest. But it seems the receiver in the manifest were never called, ATM I don't understand why, I'm searching.

Comment: I'll post some more stuff in my answer, give me a sec!

Comment: I think I found the problem. The problem is LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()). , if I used it, the receiver declared in the manifest weren't called....

Comment: Yeah it's a bit annoying that you can't use the LocalBroadcastManager for this kind of thing even though it would be perfect, but you can protect it with permissions like in my example

Comment: Mhh I don't understand something. How is called the receiver in the activity ? because we're calling a intent with permission, and this permission is not setted in this receiver, only in the manifest.

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong thing in the example!

It's:


            mainActivity.registerReceiver(this,
                    filter, 
                    YOUR_PERMISSION,
                    null);

Comment: It seems there is a problem with permission... (because if I delete it in the sendOrderedBroadcast, one of my receiver is called). I don't understand where is the problem :/

Comment: Last question :D I don't want to have multiple call to my intentservice in the same time, for few reasons.

To check if my intent is working, I've just to play with this code :

        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) act.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        } 

? There isn't another way ?

Comment: IntentServices automatically queue up your calls to them, so your requests will be handled serially - is that enough or do you actually want to  not create a request if there's already one running?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to create another request if one is running :)

Comment: You could put a static boolean in your intent service and check that?

Comment: Arf, I've again one problem with one device. With my S4 on Android 4.4.2 both receivers are called, wtf ? On my OnePlus One on Android 5.0 no problem... just one is called.

Comment: Depends on the fault -- if they're both being called at the same time then the priority is being ignored and I don't know the answer.

However, if they're being called in the correct order -- try this:

In the "intercepting" reciever, call setResultData(String) along with abortBroadcast(). In the "catch all" reciver, use "getResultData()" to see if anything has been set. If it has, then take no action

Comment: Mhh ok. In fact it seems there are executed in order. But it's strange it only in one case where the both are called, so it seems is abortBroadcast which fails because it calls the correct receiver, but it call the other receiver after it.

Comment: Must be a bug in 4.4.2 or something? Did the fix work?

Comment: Nop the fix doesn't work :/ I tried setResultData but it returns null on the second receiver when i call getResultData, and setResultCode doesn't work too. :/

Comment: Hmmm I think this warrants a new question to see what others think

Comment: I created another topic here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696013/android-mistake-with-broadcast-receivers thx for your help guy :)