# Android mistake with Broadcast / Receivers

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm using two receivers. One declared in the manifest like this :

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.app.receivertest"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="MY_PERMISSION">
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <action android:name="NAME_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And one declared in my activity A, declared with priority 1.

When I start my service on this activity A, on Android 4.4.2, both receivers are called, in the "correct order" whereas in Android 5 > 0, just the correct receiver declared in the activity A is called, not the manifest's receiver.

This is my code in the receiver used in the activity a :

```
     @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Utils.log("onReceive test");
        abortBroadcast();
        setResultData("test");
        myfunction(); 
    }
```

after this code, the other receiver is called. I tried to use "setResultData", to use "getResultData" in the other receiver for don't execute the code if I've something, but getResultData returns always null..

So, why both receivers are called ? What happens on Android 4.4 ?
I need your help :D

EDIT : Code for sending broadcast :

```
 Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(My_ACTION);
    sendOrderedBroadcast(broadcastIntent,   My_PERMISSION);
```

Comment: have you tried context.sendorderedbroadcast()

Comment: The code for sending the broadcast would be useful. And also, what is exactly the problem? Do you need both to be executed, or just the one in the activity, is currently registered? It's not easily understood from your question.

Comment: I added the code for sending the broadcast. And I need to just execute the receiver declared in my activity A.

Comment: It depends, too, on what broadcast you're trying to abort. In 5.0+, you are not allowed to intercept or abort broadcasts related to messaging functions, including dispatch/receipt of SMS messages.

Comment: Nop, no link with that :)

Comment: Nobody to help me ? :( I know I can use sharedpref" or another solution to do that, but why this code doesn't work ? The broadcast isn't the same between my two receivers ?!